# Remove Python Social Auth from django admin

Tags: django-admin, python-social-auth

I tried unregistering the models from 'social.apps.django_app.default' app.
But django says they are not registered.
I don't understand how to remove Association, Nonce and UserSocialAuth from my django admin site.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I was able to remove these by doing the following

```
from django.contrib import admin
from social.apps.django_app.default.models import Association, Nonce, UserSocialAuth

admin.site.unregister(Association)
admin.site.unregister(Nonce)
admin.site.unregister(UserSocialAuth)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to unregister those models in the my_app/urls.py and it worked for me. For example:

*my_app/urls.py:*

```
admin.site.unregister(Nonce)
```

Answer (score 1):

For me below thing worked

```
from django.contrib import admin
from social_django.models import Association, Nonce, UserSocialAuth
admin.site.unregister(Association)
admin.site.unregister(Nonce)
admin.site.unregister(UserSocialAuth)
```